# Python Pandas: Make two changes to df if a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, apply

I am new to python and trying to understand why my function is not working. Any guidance on why it is not working and how to fix would be very appreciated.

This is the df I am starting with:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  'B': [0, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                  'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'D': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  'E': ['f', 1, 2, 'd', 'e']})
df
```

I only want to evaluate columns A-C for this function. If any of the rows in column A-C is >3, I want to add 3 to the column and change the binary flag column to 1. Here is the function that I created:

```
def two_chng(self):
cols=['A','B','C']
df['NEW_BINARY']=0
for i in range(len(cols)):
    if (df[cols[i]]>3).any:
        df[cols[i]]=  df[cols[i]]+3
        df['NEW_BINARY']=1
df[cols].apply(two_chng)
df
```

What I want my resulting data to look like is this: I do not understand the first row had 9 added to each column subsequent column has added the value of row 1 to itself.

```
res= pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
                  'B': [0, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                  'C': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8],
                  'D': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  'E': ['f', 1, 2, 'd', 'e'],
                  'NEW_BINARY': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use boolean masks:

```
# columns of interest
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

# identify values > 3
m = df[cols].gt(3)

# increment them
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m, df[cols]+3)

# set the flag if any value was >3 per row
df['NEW_BINARY'] = m.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  D  E  NEW_BINARY
0  0   0  1  a  f           0
1  1   9  2  b  1           1
2  2  10  3  c  2           1
3  3  11  7  d  d           1
4  7  12  8  e  e           1
```

Comment: damn, almost identical solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's pritty straightforward:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']

# where value > 3
mask = df[cols].gt(3)

# add 3 to where it's > 3
df[cols] += mask * 3

# new binary 
df['NEW_BINARY'] = mask.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  D  E  NEW_BINARY
0  0   0  1  a  f           0
1  1   9  2  b  1           1
2  2  10  3  c  2           1
3  3  11  7  d  d           1
4  7  12  8  e  e           1
```

Comment: it's \*pr**e**tty ;)